# Syntax regarding classes (Java)

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have a main, class A, and class B (class B has inherited from A).

from my main I create an array and have inside both A's and B's.

```
Object[] tab = new Object[7];
tab[0] = new B(-10);
tab[1] = new A();
```

I then call methods from the class

```
((A) tab[2]).analyser(tab[1]);
((B) tab[5]).analyser(tab[1]);
```

I get confused in this part regarding (A) & (B). (both classes have a method called analyser). I don't understand the point of it (why is there an (A) and (B) before tab, and what is the purpose), my guess is, we are calling the array but in the shape of class A - >(A) and (b) respectively... but it doesn't convince me.

It's part of a bigger coding, but I was hoping that this would be enough to get my answer.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Java (not java script)

Comment: Is it complete example? Because, clearly, `tab[2]` is uninitialised. Anyway, thing is that `Object` have no method `analyse`, so you casting object to class 'A' or 'B'. Having array of 'A' would remove this requirement (unless method is declared as `final`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, this code could be equivalently represented like this:

```
A[] tab = new A[7];
tab[0] = new B(-10); // permitted since B derives from A
tab[1] = new A();
// ...
tab[2].analyser(tab[1]);
tab[5].analyser(tab[1]);
```

In general, when declaring an array it is best use the most specific type that can contain all the objects the array is expected to hold.  If an array is expect to hold any object (strings, other arrays, `A`, etc.), it can only be declared as an `object[]` (and store any type that inherits from `Object`).  If the array is only expected to hold types derived from `A` (e.g., `A` and `B`), then it can be declared as an `A[]` and store any type that inherits from `A` (e.g., `A` and `B`).

In the original code, the syntax `((A)tab[2])` was used to cast `tab[2]` to a more-derived type (in this case, `A`); it in essence tells the compiler, "regard `tab[2]` as though it were declared as an `A`".  Since `tab` is defined as an array of `Object`s, and `Object` does not contain an `analyser` method, you need to cast to a class that defines the method you want to invoke (here `analyser`).

Even though `tab[0]` is defined as as an instance of `B`, it can be cast upward to a less-derived type, `A`.  In this case, calling (`((A)tab[0]).analyzer(tab[1])` and (`((B)tab[0]).analyser(tab[1])`) are functionally equivalent, even if `B` has its own definition provided for `analyser`.  (This concept is known as polymorphism.)